# When i want add a object from request json in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, arraylist

Well, I consult a JSON object by url , I get the object and add it to a string, there all right, the problem is when I add it to the `ArrayList` this line is skipped and not executed when we add , anyone know why?

```
public void consult(String val_user){

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            "http://"+ippref+":8080/Activo/webresources/activo.entities.historialactivos/consulta/"+val_user+"", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            String item = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    item += "Actividad: " + obj.getString("actividad") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Activo NS: " + obj.getString("activo") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Fecha: " + obj.getString("fecha") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Id Activo: " + obj.getString("idActivo") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Id Historial: " + obj.getString("idHistorialActivo") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Id Incidencia: " + obj.getString("idIncidencia") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Id Usuario: " + obj.getString("idUsuario") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Incidencia: " + obj.getString("incidencia") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Observaciones: " + obj.getString("observaciones") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Oficina: " + obj.getString("oficina") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Tipo de movimiento: " + obj.getString("tipoMovimiento") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Usuario: " + obj.getString("usuario" + "\r\n");

                    array.add(item);

                    item = "";


                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                metodo_adapter();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

In `array.add(item)` when I do execute the debug skip the line of code.

Answer (score 2):

```
array.add(item);
item = ""; // This line is causing issue.
```

Don't make your item string empty like this because String is a reference based variable and if you will do like this you will end up storing " " in your array.

Better define your `String item = "";` inside try block

Comment: I remove that line but still the same error, the line  array.add(item)  execution point fail, dont add

Comment: I was expecting it to work in that way. May I know how you have declared and initiated "array"?

Comment: private List<String> arrayactivos = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 2):

only problem because you put

```
String item = "";
```

outside for loop ,, this mean all array list look to single object , mean only last one will be have data

solution must do this

```
     for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
String item = "";
                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    item += "Actividad: " + obj.getString("actividad") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Activo NS: " + obj.getString("activo") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Fecha: " + obj.getString("fecha") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Id Activo: " + obj.getString("idActivo") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Id Historial: " + obj.getString("idHistorialActivo") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Id Incidencia: " + obj.getString("idIncidencia") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Id Usuario: " + obj.getString("idUsuario") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Incidencia: " + obj.getString("incidencia") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Observaciones: " + obj.getString("observaciones") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Oficina: " + obj.getString("oficina") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Tipo de movimiento: " + obj.getString("tipoMovimiento") + "\r\n";
                    item += "Usuario: " + obj.getString("usuario" + "\r\n");

                    array.add(item);

                    item = "";


                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                metodo_adapter();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
```

will solve your problem